# Delete dupes in MySQL db based on two tables joined

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I am looking for a way to delete duplicates based not only on one table, but two.

Table 1:

```
ID | NAME      | ETC
1  | Truck     | 
2  | Boat      |
3  | Truck     |
4  | Truck     |
```

Table 2

```
ID  | REL_ID | KEY        |  VAL
450 | 1      | operator   |  Jim
451 | 2      | operator   |  Frank
452 | 3      | operator   |  Jake
453 | 4      | operator   |  Jim
```

I want to search for duplicates in such a way that **I only retrieve record #4** from table 1; the titles from Table 1 need to dupe but ALSO their related keys in Table 2 (eg rec 1 and rec 3 are also dupes, but they have different operators). So far I have tried to inner join the table 2 twice, but i keep getting confused on how nested to do. Thank you!

EDIT: Desired result: I wish to run a query that only selects row 4 in table 1 for **deletion**, because it is a duplicate both in its Name (Truck and Truck) as well as in its related operator (Jim and Jim).  If I deleted all dupes with Truck as name, I'd also delete those that have different operators.

An example query I've had that selects (for deletion) all dupes from Table 1 would be:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.title
FROM table_1 AS a
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
      FROM table_1
      GROUP BY title
      HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
   ) AS b ON b.title = a.title
AND b.min_id <> a.id
```

This gets me dupes from table 1, but unsure how to roll in table 2.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish here. Can you give an example query and an example desired row output that might help describe the problem you're facing?

Comment: _I only retrieve record #4_ -- why not `2-Boat`? That does not appear to have any duplicates. Can you post a table of what exactly the output of your query would look like?

Comment: by retrieve do you mean delete? or keep? and do you want to delete from both tables?

Comment: I modified my question and gave a sample query, thanks. @pala_ I do mean to delete, but selecting is fine too, I can change the query.

Comment: do you want to delete from both tables?

Comment: That would be helpful, but table 1 is the crucial. I can then sweep table 2 and delete all orphaned relative 'operator' keys.

Answer (score 1):

This will delete the value out of both tables for you:

```
delete  t, tt from table1 t inner join table2 tt on t.id = tt.rel_id where t.id in (select * from (select max(t1.id)
  from table1 t1
    inner join table2 t2
      on t1.id = t2.rel_id
  group by t1.name, t2.val
  having count(t1.name) > 1)q)
```

the subquery is nested twice because mysql is picky about how you use the table you want to delete from in subqueries.

it wont delete more than one dupe of the same item - let me know if it needs to

There's a demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b7ea/1

This version will delete ALL of the dupes and only leave the one with the lowest id:

```
 delete x, xx from table1 x inner join table2 xx on x.id = xx.rel_id where x.id in (select * from (
select t.id from table1 t
  inner join
    (select min(t1.id) m, t1.name, t2.val
           from table1 t1
             inner join table2 t2
               on t1.id = t2.rel_id
         group by t1.name, t2.val
         having count(t1.name) > 1
    ) q
    on t.id > q.m and t.name = q.name
  inner join
    table2 t2
      on t.id = t2.rel_id
        and t2.val = q.val) qx)
```

demo for that one here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62312/1

Comment: Sorry, it will delete the value or the whole row?

Comment: the row, sorry for the confusion

Comment: When I run this, I'm still seeing that it selects rows 1, 3 and 4 - not strictly 4.

Comment: how? it runs fine on your sample data - see the demos.  try just running the selects inside the `in` clause - it should show you the ids for the rows that will be deleted

Comment: @dama_do_bling i've also just updated both versions of the query to delete from both tables, with similarly updated fiddles

Comment: _pala please see this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/1Z1JGEG0 - i am trying to use this on a wordpress set of tables. i'm still getting ALL dupes, including ones that have different meta_values (or "VAL" in table 2 above)

Comment: @dama_do_bling can you please post some actual real sample data then, as opposed to what you have in the question - because the above queries work fine on the data as you've presented it